# When deploying to Heroku, is there something I need to add/change in the production entry in the database.yml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I am using `postgresql` as the database in my development environment, so that means that I setup my `database.yml` like the code below where the `username` and `password` is my postgresql's username and password (obviously, I'm using environment variables to avoid hard-coding) and will be inherited by `development` and `test` environments:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
  # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: localhost
  username: <%= ENV['FOO_DATABASE_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['FOO_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

I'm just curious about the production environment, which has the code below:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: foo_production
  username: foo
  password: <%= ENV['FOO_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Unlike in the `development` and `test` environments which uses my postgresql's username and password, the `production` environment have different values for `username` and `password`.

My question is, do I need to change the `username` and `password` in the `production` environment? or should I just leave it as it is?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connecting-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

What you're talking about here is essentially how you can make your code work in multiple environments (development and production), with multiple different database credentials.

The way this is typically handled is through environment variables.

In your example above, it looks like you've created two environment variables for your local database:

- `PINTERESTING_APP_DATABASE_USERNAME`
- `PINTERESTING_APP_DATABASE_PASSWORD`

In production, I'm assuming you have some different environment variables set which contain your production Postgres credentials.

What you need to do in your code is select one of these two options, and use them everywhere.

Here's some pseudo-code I use in my applications to accomplish this:

```
DATABASE_HOST = ENV['LOCAL_DB_HOST'] || ENV['PRODUCTION_DB_HOST']
DATABASE_PORT = ENV['LOCAL_DB_PORT'] || ENV['PRODUCTION_DB_PORT']
DATABASE_USERNAME = ENV['LOCAL_DB_USERNAME'] || ENV['PRODUCTION_DB_USERNAME']
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ENV['LOCAL_DB_PASSWORD'] || ENV['PRODUCTION_DB_PASSWORD']
```

As you can see above, what I'm doing is either using my development credentials, OR my production credentials, depending on which environment variables are available.

This allows me to seamlessly switch between development and production environments by just modifying environment variables (which is what Heroku does).